# How to customize commit name for sheduled builds in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline that will run on a scheduled.

When I mannually queue the build I get the option to give the commit name:

[image]

But when I want to trigger the build based on a schedule it takes the commit name of the previous task:

[image]

Is it possible to provide commit names, with build id's or date to make them unique, for the scheduled builds.

Already tried a lot of options and ATM I can only modify the build numberr in the options panel and not the commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Commit field in that dialog is not a name you can give to a commit, but rather the commit hash you'd like to build.

If you leave it blank, then the `HEAD` of the chosen branch will be checked out and built. It works exactly like this when the build is run by a trigger. But if you'd like to run a build for some past state of your repository, you can enter a particular Git commit hash here, and Azure Pipelines will switch to that commit once it checks out the sources.